# How to lock the arrow keys to the alternative function of Home/End/PgUp/PgDown keys on Dell XPS 15?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, dell-xps, fn-key

How is it possible to lock the arrow keys to the alternative function of Home/End/PgUp/PgDown keys on Dell XPS 15 (9560)?

The dell XPS 15 9560 uses the Fn key in combination with the up, down, left, right arrow keys to achieve this task of pgup, pgdn, home, end, respectively.  However, it is not user-friendly to have to press the Fn key to PageUp or PageDown - especially for accessibility (e.g. one-handed typing.)

Is there any way to lock the arrow keys to their respective alternative functions, since Fn+Esc does not lock them (it only locks some of the F-keys), and as such, Fn must still be pressed, requiring two hands.

Comment: Have you tried enabling sticky keys?

Comment: That wouldn't work - sticky keys is only for Ctrl, Alt, Winkey, Shift - unfortunately, not Fn.  Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Download AutoHotkey - https://autohotkey.com/

Step 2: Right-click desktop - New - AutoHotKey Script

Step 3: Right-click the script - Edit with notepad

Step 4: Create the following four scripts

**AHK Script 1:**

Up::

Send, {PgUp}

**AHK Script 2**

Down::

Send, {PgDn}

**AHK Script 3**

Left::

Send, {Home}

**AHK Script 4**

Right::

Send, {End}

Step 5: Double click each script to activate and hey presto your keys are remapped.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I have seen is to use AutoHotkey and map Right Shift + Arrow Key to the appropriate function. Not perfect but at least it allows for one handed use.

Comment: True but it is the best 'solution' as there is no way to 'lock' the arrow keys as the original question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing FN+Esc to lock the function key. This should allow you to use the secondary actions mapped to the arrow keys.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but as I said in the question: Fn+Esc does not lock the arrow keys to their alternative function, it only locks some of the F-keys.