# Enable Fn lock on some keys only

Tags: keyboard, fn-key, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I recently got a Surface Pro i5 128GB with the type cover. The SP 4 Type Cover looks like [this](https://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSImages/SP4_Typecover_Teal_FrontView_V1.jpg?version=7c4d0b4c-934d-6c43-d1cb-56ed55fe57be).

I am looking for a way to make all the function keys to behave as function keys, but the <kbd>PrtScr (F7)</kbd>, <kbd>Home (F8)</kbd>, and <kbd>End (F9)</kbd> keys should function as the PrtScr, Home, and End keys respectively.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want isn’t possible.

Comment: Really? Not even by changing registry values or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is:

Fn + Caps = Toggle Function Keys Always ON/OFF

Reference:
http://www.surfaceproblog.com/trick-lock-the-fn-key/

You must remap the function keys to get Print/Home/End back

Here's the script commands for those three keys:

**AHK Script 1:**

F8:

Send, {Home}

**AHK Script 2:**

F9:

Send, {End}

**AHK Script 3:**

F7::

Send, {PrintScreen}

### -

### -

You can create a script that re-maps any other key to execute one of those lines.

Download:
https://autohotkey.com/

Comment: This works with some further information here: https://superuser.com/questions/1289531/how-to-lock-the-arrow-keys-to-the-alternative-function-of-home-end-pgup-pgdown-k, however it has to be `f8::` with two colons at the end to redefine the mapping

Comment: To also enable commands such as shift+end, you can also add e,g: `+f9:: Send, +{End}` to the scripts